# Why does NodeJS terminate execution without throwing an exception?

Tags: node.js, recursion, exception, stack-overflow, throw

Adding the console.log in this recursive function prevents NodeJS from throwing a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" exception. Instead it just exits after a couple thousand iterations with no message (using Node v16.6.0 on Win10).

Why does the console.log change the exception throwing behavior, and how should I catch this exception without removing the console.log?

(In browsers it also throws an exception as I expected.)

```
function recursive(i) {
    console.log(i)
    return recursive(i + 1) * 2
}
    
try {
    recursive(0)
} catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
}
```

Comment: I modified the code to prevent tail call optimization. This has no effect on the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There is no expected exception here.

Semantically, this is an infinite loop, which is valid. If the JS engine doesn't do [tail call optimization](https://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html) infinite recursion (like your example) will cause the call stack to overflow, but this is neither required nor desired. The ECMAScript standard even states how [tail calls should be optimized](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-tail-position-calls), though this isn't implemented in most JS engines (except for JavaScriptCore used in Safari/WebKit). Whether Node emits the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` exception or not is nothing you should rely on.

Comment: Just curious why, when I remove the console.log it does throw an exception. In either case, execution does terminate after a few thousand iterations. Thanks.